# jQuery Ajax Post keep adding username and password on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the Login Dialog as mentioned [here on jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-login-dialog/) which I think is not the problem I am having and hence it shouldn't matter if someone has used it before or not for answering my question:

When testing the login functionality by putting login credentials, the username and password keep getting added on the URL of the page which I don't want. I am not sure why it's happening. Am I doing something wrong with the jQuery Ajax Post Webservice call?

Say for example, my home page URL of the webapp is : `https://example.com/home.html`

After entering loging credentials, it gets added to the URL for some reason like this:

`https://example.com/home.html?username=myname&password=mypassword`

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Login HTML Begins -->
            <div id="wrap">

            <div id="window" caption="Login">
                <div>
                    <form >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Username:</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" name="user" id = "username" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password:</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 150px;" type="password" name="password" id = "password" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="bottom">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Login HTML ends -->
```

Here is my Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#window').jqxWindow({ theme: "shinyblack", width: 250, height: 130, isModal: true });
        $('#submit').jqxButton({ theme: "shinyblack" });

      var loginUrl = "https://example.com:8443/Webservice/loginCheck"

 $( "#submit" ).click(function() {

                var userName = $("#username").val();
                 var passWord = $("#password").val();

                var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
                    //beforeSend: TODO: show spinner!
                    data: {
                        username: userName,
                        passWord: passWord 
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: "POST",
                    url: loginUrl
                })
                 .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {

                // Validate the web service and retrieve the status.
                if (typeof (data_) === "undefined" || data_ === null) { alert("Invalid data returned from LoginCheck Web Service"); return false; }
                if (isEmpty(data_.webservice_status) || isEmpty(data_.webservice_status.status)) { alert("Invalid Web Service Status for LoginCheck Webservice!"); return false; }
                if (data_.webservice_status.status != "SUCCESS") {   alert(data_.webservice_status.message); 


                return false; }
            })

           .fail(function (jqXHR_, textStatus_, errorThrown_) {
                    alert("Hitting the Fail function : Error in LoginCheck webservice: " + errorThrown_);
                    return false;
                });


}




    });
</script>
```

Comment: A forms default behaviour is to submit/send data, you need to tell it not to. you can use `return false` or `event.preventDefault();` I suggest you look at how to disable form submitting, this will allow the javascript to run.

Comment: You need to explicitly use `<form method="post">` so force a POST request. It defaults to a GET request when the `method` attribute is not specified.

Comment: @Terry Would the AJAX work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default protocol used by forms are GET so you need to override it using POST protocol

so you need something like this:

```
<form action="url" method="post">
 ..
  ..
 ..
</form>
```

also the embedded click function you should prevent some default by putting this code :

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  <!-- your statement !>
 ...
})
```

also the butto type :

```
 <button type="button" id="submit"></button>
```

or

```
 <input type="button" id="submit">
```

Comment: By specifying URL in form action attribute, don't you think it will directly be calling that URL without parameters and my ajaxCall seems to be doing same thing? Please correct me if wrong. Thanks

Comment: you can remove the url

Comment: You should actually still allow normal, JS-free login by specifying the `action` attribute. So that if your JS is invalid (by mistake, perhaps) or when your client disabled JS, they can still be logged in normally. The purpose of AJAX is to supplement static pages, not a replacement thereof.

Comment: @Terry Thanks. But if I keep the URL in the action attribute, how would I be passing username and password?

Comment: @Terry The way the code is arranged, the form is likely a kind of popup so it's going to need javascript anyway. As well, the percentage of users who have javascript unavailable is so small that it's no big loss to make javascript a requirement of using a site.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set it up, you're submitting the form data in the traditional way rather than via AJAX.

One option is to add:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

(A common error is to try to prevent form submission in a click handler attached to the submit button. There are a number of ways to submit a form and the submit button is only one of them.)

Another option is to just remove the `form` element.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `form` element and that seems to be much better option.

Answer (score 0):

Your form may be sending a get request, because you haven't prevented the default functionality of a form button. Try adding these two lines to your click handler:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```